# Customize Curl animation in iphone?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, core-animation

I want to set animation for my UIView. I am using CurlUp animation for that. My requirement is to use CurlLeft and CurlRight. These are not available in CoreAnimation as I know. So is there any way by which I can handle the CurlLeft and CurlRight. I don't know a lot about OpenGl. But I don't have any problem with that too. Please guide me and provide me any link by which I can handle CurlLeft and right animation using either OpenGL or CoreAnimation.

Thanks a Lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For page turning animations, Ole Begemann has done something like that. His code is available on Github. See my answer to this question for a link.

[iBook page flip transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805038/ibook-page-flip-transaction/5805097#5805097)

His sample project is available for download and shows page curling left and right.