# iBook page flip transition

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, animation, page-curl

I'm trying recreate iBook like transition for pages in landscape mode for an pdf reader app. I only need the animation, not the, touch handling like iBook app; the user with a simple swipe turn the page. I have tried different sample code, including Leaves, but I can't find anything simple. 
Can Anyone help me to create this simple animation, or there's a simple way to recreate iBook transition?

Comment: Leaves is an excellent project that is easy and simple to include in projects.

Comment: There's a way to modify Leaves to only do the transition between pages without tracking touches?

Comment: Leaves also support landscape orientation with two pages?

Comment: there are different forks of Leaves which include landscape with 2 pages: https://github.com/ansani/leaves

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ole Begemann has done something like this. You can find the project [here on GitHub](https://github.com/ole/leaves).

Ole also writes a superb blog summary of some of the best developer links and tutorials around. Well worth subscribing to!

Comment: I don't want to use the Leaves framework because I only need the animation, I don't need to track the touch of the user. I only need the animation of the flipping page.

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to use it without the touch tracking. You could remove that part of the code and replace it with an animation curve.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the UIView documentation for animation types available.  Here is what I'd use:

```
UIViewAnimationOptions animation;
if (pageNumberLower) {
    animation = UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown;
} else {
    animation = UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp;
}

[UIView transitionWithView:myChangingView
                  duration:0.5
                   options:animation
                animations:^{ CHANGE PAGE HERE }
                completion:NULL];
```

Comment: This certainly looks nice, but is nothing compared to the iBook page flip animation.