# Complete list of transitions you can do between views on iPhone/ iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Are there many other resources for doing creative transitions between views? I am familiar with the following, but I am wondering if there are any more out there. Links to tutorials, examples, source code and API's would be wonderful.

[Modal View Controller Example](http://timneill.net/2010/09/modal-view-controller-example-part-1/)

[View Transitions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ViewTransitions/Introduction/Intro.html)

Thanks!

---

**EDIT 1**

Just found this project which is pretty cool. Allows page turning like a book on PDFs and images

[Page Turner](https://github.com/ole/leaves)

which was found on this [SOF post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805038/ibook-page-flip-transaction). There is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477078/turn-a-page-like-a-book-with-uiview/4946405#4946405) which is in the same vein.

Comment: +1 I've my eyes on, at the answers for this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good idea!

There is also the HMGLTransitions to make cool 3D transitions. 
The sources are available on github here: [HMGLTransitions](https://github.com/Split82/HMGLTransitions). ([Video](http://youtu.be/gWRcf5Y3TJY))

Answer (score 5):

One thing I found is that you have "hidden" built in transitions between views when you push them upon the navigationcontroller.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController transition:6];
```

Some of the numbers I know is:

- 1: the bar and the view goes to the left
- 2: the bar goes to the left and the content to the right
- 3: both goes to the right (similar to the normal animation)
- 6: Fade
- 10: Some kind of crazy flip

No idea how many it is but it's worth looking in to if you want something different for free!

Comment: Wow. This one definitely seems useful. Nice one.

Comment: Is this trick safe for AppStore?

Comment: It won't flag on any of their automated systems and will probably get through. However, you're going to have to check that they keep on working on every version of iOS as they'll probably break in some future version.

Comment: @Alastair: What leads you to believe that this would be accepted? `-pushViewController:transition:` isn't in any public documentation. I'd recommend against its use, even if Apple has overlooked it in the past.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't realise this wasn't a public API.