# How can I make slide down transition animation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I can see a lot of transition animation: from left to right, right to left, fading, but how can I make transition from the top down to bottom?

Thanks for all help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605959/implement-custom-animation-to-present-modal-view-from-specified-view-on-ipad

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188584/complete-list-of-transitions-you-can-do-between-views-on-iphone-ipad/7328633#7328633

Answer (score 2):

Try working out this...
Add QuartzCore framework

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

CATransition *transDown=[CATransition animation];
[transDown setDuration:0.5];
[transDown setType:kCATransitionPush];
[transDown setSubtype:kCATransitionFromBottom];
[transDown setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

[Boottom_view.layer addAnimation:transDown forKey:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:modalViewController animated:YES];
```

and hiding it like this:

```
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Yea , I am using something like this too, but can't find the way to make it move from top to bottom

Comment: see this link..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237310/how-can-i-change-the-animation-style-of-a-modal-uiviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Your could use Core Animation, what sort of object are you using?

Basically, to fade in an object you do this:

```
[[objectName animator] setOpacity: 1];
```

Remember you first need to set the opacity to 0 etc. before the animation begins.
Hope this is what your wanting.

Answer (score 0):

You set your view frame to it's starting position offscreen and then your bring your frame into position with some animation.

```
CGRect originalFrame = [detailsView frame];
CGRect offscreenFrame = originalFrame;
offscreenFrame.origin.y -= offscreenFrame.size.height; 
detailsView.frame = offscreenFrame;  //Send the frame above screen        

//Add view here if necessary to an unscrew view
// [aSuperView addSubview:detailsView];

[UIView beginAnimations:@"BringIn" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
detailsView.frame = originalFrame
[UIView commitAnimations];
```